# Make all network traffic from PC1 pass through PC2

Tags: networking, routing

I'd like to have all network traffic pass through a computer, so that I can write some scripts that do basic traffic analysis (want to create a simple firewall).

I have a home wireless network and several machines on it. I have a desktop with a wireless card and a LAN card. The desktop is only running Windows 7 now, but I can install Ubuntu.

I'd like to use an ethernet cable to connect my laptop to my desktop, then have the desktop 'share' its internet connection – and as all of my laptop's data passes through the desktop I'd like to access it somehow.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Connect a hub to your router and all your PC's to the hub. That way, your terminals will receive all the network traffic regardless of whether the IP packages were aimed to them or not.

Comment: How would he set up his firewall on the desktop for the other machines doing it like this? Also, this is at least borderline not an answer, since the user has a very different solution in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If the desktop PC runs Windows you can use [Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126)

You should be able to monitor traffic arriving on the etherne

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 ethernet ports on the computer that will be analyzing the traffic, connect one to the router and the other to the other PC. View your network connections, select the two ones that you are using, and use the "bridge connections" feature. (it might have been renamed to something else, but it was called that in Windows XP.) Software like ethereal or wireshark can be used to analyze the traffic